# Retrieving file from database in c# using asp.net webform

Tags: c#

I used the asp.net web form to save and retrieve data from the database. I am able to save it in database and while retrieving it is always downloading the first file that is stored in database.

code used to download  is :

```
   private void download(int id)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetFiles", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;              
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
        string Name = dt.Rows[0]["FileName"].ToString();
        byte[] documentBytes = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;FileName={0}", Name));
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length",documentBytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(documentBytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
    }
```

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure code please?

Comment: You are only processing the first row of the `DataTable` at: `string Name = dt.Rows[0]["FileName"].ToString();`

Instead you need a loop. But you can't download multiple files. You could create a zip file  instead.

Comment: Is there any way to download the files.

Comment: @TimSchmelter correct me please but I can't see anywhere in the question that indicates they want to download multiple files. They are pulling the first (and only?) row from the result set so it seemed to be that they were not getting the expected row so the contents of the stored procedure may help.

Comment: @ R Day yaa even i think let me share my Procedure

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetFiles]
(@Id int)
as
select Id,Data,FileName,FileExtension
from FilesData

Comment: @RDay yaa you are right. I am not able to retrieve required row rather downloading the first row always.

Comment: Instead of `select Id,Data,FileName,FileExtension from FilesData` you need: `select Id,Data,FileName,FileExtension from FilesData WHERE Id = @Id`

Comment: @yani can you add the stored procedure code to the question please?

Comment: @Tim.. ohhh Sorry man I didn't see that. I hope it will work now. Thankyou guys .for ther help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that you really have forgotten to add the `WHERE`-clause in your stored-procedure. Instead of

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetFiles] (@Id int) as 
SELECT Id,Data,FileName,FileExtension 
FROM FilesData
```

You need to apply a filter with `WHERE`:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetFiles] (@Id int) as 
SELECT Id,Data,FileName,FileExtension 
FROM FilesData
WHERE Id = @Id
```